# How to get back a file which filename contains whitespace in GNU Parallel

Tags: linux, bash

GNU Parallel is a great tool, but I have problem with receiving the processed files back. Consider this option:

```
--trc "output/Done {}"
```

as the result I get error that file

```
output/Done
```

does not exist.

How I can pass the filename to Parallel for return, when (as above) it contains a whitespace?

**Info:**

If you are not fully familiar with GNU Parallel, --trc is abbrevation of transfer, return, cleanup and {} is a substitution for every processed element from input, in my case it is filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something somewhere is forgetting to quote an argument. This is quite common in shell scripts, but I'd imagine that something similar could happen in Perl as well (which is what GNU Parallel is written in).

Also, [Func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/).

Comment: Thank you for the link! But back to my problem -- so are you saying that it is not my fault, but it is rather a bug in Parallel, right?

Comment: Assuming that nothing else comes into play, yes.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel is designed to give you as few surprises as possible, so this is clearly a bug. Please file a bug report https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=parallel

The workaround until the bug is fixed is:

```
--trc "output/Done\\ {}"
```